# Undefined index PHP code

Tags: php, ajax, html

I have this php that uses ajax

**cotizaciones.php**

```
        <script>
        function showUser(str)
        {
            if (str == "")
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
```

I have another script as above, except that it is called calcularCuotas(cuotas) and the last lines are:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?c=" + str, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
```

The body tag contains:

```
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<select name="cuotas" onchange="calcularCuota(this.value)">
```

The file **getuser.php**

```
    <?php 
$q = $_GET["q"]; 
$c = $_GET["c"]; 
?>
```

When I try to use it, php throws this error:

***Notice: Undefined index: c in C:\wamp\www\Cotizacion\getuser.php on line 3***

Thanks for help :)

Comment: What about the error message don't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first code block i.e cotizaciones.php

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
```

it does not contain c as querystring hence you get error undefined index c

Comment: There's a same method that contains c on the query string, and still not working

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax library of Jquery it's just an advice.

[Jquery:Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)